# My category navigation layered navigation is showing no products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, layered-navigation

I am newbie in Magento 2, I configured the Magento 2 layered Navigation and did everything to set layered navigation for categories and size and color.

Layered Navigation is working perfect for color but not for categories and size.
When i select any size in Magento 2 layered navigation it shows no product but at side it shows number of products in that category.

I think this is Magento 2 bug, because i tried every settings and looked at every overriding file to check if there's any file causing error.

Here is what it seems like
[image]

[image]

For size it is showing only first and last size but not all sizes in siz attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this problem was, 
**I have to set Another attribute, which is already presented in the Magento 2 CAT's setting to filter with result to No**. 
So, that it can display the categories related to category attribute not to Cat attribute which was predefined in the Magento 2. It was somehow linked to each other. When i select category it search for that categories in Cat attribute and that's why got blank result.

Comment: i think this is magento default issue, strange that magento implemented something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that it's a bug. However, you can fix it temporarily. Replace these codes in **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php**:

```
)->join(                                                                                                                                                                     
    ['cpa' => $attribute->getBackend()->getTable()],                                                                                                                         
    'cpe.' . $aiField . ' = cpa.' . $aiField,                                                                                                                                
    ['store_id', 'value']
```

with these lines:

```
)->join(                                                                                                                                                                     
    ['cpa' => $attribute->getBackend()->getTable()],                                                                                                                         
    'cpe.' . $aiField . ' = cpa.' . 'row_id' //$aiField,                                                                                                                                
    ['store_id', 'value']
```

Comment: This is not working and the code you provided is different in my magento file. i am currently using 2.2.5 Version of magento 2. The code looks like
)->join(
                ['cpa' => $attribute->getBackend()->getTable()],
                'cpe.' . $fieldMainTable . ' = cpa.' . $fieldJoinTable,
                ['store_id', 'value'], I tried you code but didn't worked.